# How to get values of tableview cells having multiple selections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview in which i have provided checkmarks as a accessory to multiple cells.
Now I want to get values of all those cells having checkmarks.

```
#import "HealthIssues.h"

@interface HealthIssues ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* checkedIndexPath;


@end

@implementation HealthIssues
@synthesize HealthIssuesTV;
@synthesize checkedIndexPath;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    PickerList=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"None" ,@"Diabetes", @"Heart Problem" , @"Thyroid" , @"Over Weight" , @"Kidney Issues" , @"Lever Issues" , @"Vitamins Deficiency" , @"Blood Pressure" ,  nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [PickerList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==Nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }


    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        if ([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
        {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [PickerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    {
        int z=0;
            if (indexPath.row==0)
                {
                        NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells];
                            for (UITableViewCell *cell in visibleCells)
                            {
                                if (z==0)
                                {
                                     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
                                    z++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                                    z++;
                                }
                            }
                }
            else
                {
                                if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
                                {
                                    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                                }
                         [tableView reloadData];
                }

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}



  @end
```

This Works perfect for me as per my requirements. now i want to store selected rows in dictionary.

Comment: while selecting cells u can add those index path to an array.

Comment: check this link http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19244/ios-uitableview-saving-cell-checkmarks-to-disk

Comment: You should be tracking which cells are selected in some way (a set of indexPaths works very well), and then be able to access your datasource using those indexPaths, just as you do in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: this link should helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860106/2069114

Comment: show my code and do right mark if it will help you so it will helpful for other

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface selectUsers ()
{
    NSMutableArray *selected_ids;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selected_ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *_id = [[yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"_id"];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        [selected_ids removeObject:_id];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    } else {
        [selected_ids addObject:_id];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Use selected_ids array where you want.

Comment: plz make right to this answer if is it true so it will helpful for others.

Comment: See the coding I shared above and try to help according to that one please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get values from your data source of array and get all selected rows of UITableView:
Following code will give you all indexpaths of selected rows:

```
NSArray *arrIndexpaths = [YourTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]; // Returns indexpaths for multiple selection in Table view.
```

Then Get value from the array by indexpath.row and indexpath.section whatever you used during in data source method.

Comment: See the coding I shared above and try to help according to that one please.

Comment: @NavjotSingh what type of dictionary you want?

Comment: I have a mutable dictionary.you can store those in array also .

Comment: You require all selected indexpath in one array right?

Comment: When ever you define UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark at that place add current IndexPath into mutable array and when doing UITableViewCellAccessoryNone remove that indexpath from the array

Comment: I already tried that. but please answer with DETAILED coding so that I can check if I am left with any thing.....

Comment: I tried that when i m putting checkmark,it add object in array but with that my started crashing saying reason that array don't have value.....so i undo eveything.

Comment: That would be other reason for crashing just redo all the things and show me that exact code that i can help you...!

Comment: That was exactly same as Bandish Dave suggested.  check it out its first answer on top

Comment: Ya that was right now put the exception break point and tell me where it crashes the app.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception  NSRangeExceptions reason - NSArrayMobjectAtIndex  index0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: it occurs after completing viewdidload part.

Comment: Make sure you allocate the array on viewdidLoad

Comment: Yes i copy same from Bandish Dave

Comment: Now it crashed before viewdidload when accessing in cellforrowarindex

Comment: can you join on team viewer?

Comment: I don't have just put the screenshot

Comment: give me your mail id. Will send you the screen shots

Comment: james.cloudios@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should do:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Then you can get list of selected rows by:

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

As you have now list of selected rows, you can get row or data of row.

Comment: See the coding I shared above and try to help according to that one please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array for this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    arrData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` add your value into array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [arrData addObject:[YourDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

`NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes ;` // instance variable, do initialization in viewDidLoad

i am assuming that you are using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for selecting cell (i mean not a custom button action)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if ([selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath])
   {
    [selectedIndexes removeObject:indexPath];
   }
   else
   {
    [selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];
   }
}
```

Now you can get all selected cells using index values in `selectedIndexes` array

for ex `UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:1];`

edit :

remove all objects from selectedIndexes after selection process is over

Comment: See the coding I shared above and try to help according to that one please.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface RestTableViewController ()<UISearchBarDelegate>{
NSMutableSet *setTemp;
//    NSMutableArray *setTemp;
}
```

In ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

setTemp = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
 . . . 
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
[self markCell:cell atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Create a Method

```
- (void)markCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndex:(NSInteger)index{
if ([setTemp containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
}
```

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

{
    // Restaurent is my Object File
    Restaurent *obj = [restMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([setTemp containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]]) {
        [setTemp removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
         // tempMainArray is an array which manages the title of selected or deselected Rows . . . 
        [tempMainArray removeObject:obj.strTitle];
         NSLog(@"Selected Row Data %@",tempMainArray);
    }
    else {

        [setTemp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
        [tempMainArray addObject:obj.strTitle];
        NSLog(@"Selected Row Data %@",tempMainArray);
    }
        [self markCell:cell atIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

To Select All The Cell

```
#pragma mark : Select All Data Method. . .
- (IBAction)actionBtnClicked:(id)sender {
{
    [setTemp removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [restMutableArray count]; i++) {
      Restaurent *obj = [restMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [tempMainArray addObject:obj.strTitle];
        [setTemp addObject:@(i)];
    }
     NSLog(@"%@",tempMainArray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```